# The inequality used to study a trigonometric function's sign has no solutions

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, proof-verification, graphing-functions

The function, sign of which we are asked to study, is:

$$f(x) = 2\sin(x)\cos(x) - 1,$$

or, simplified:

$$f(x) = \sin(2x)-1,$$

**without using its graph** to do so, since the exercise itself asks, in the end, to plot the function's behaviour in a approximate graph.

If I were to study its sign how I would usually do for more complex functions, I would say:

$$\sin(2x) \geq 1,$$

which **never** happens, excluding the case in which $\sin(2x) = 1$ .

At this point, I would likely say that the function is never greater than 1, and is, hence, always negative. Am I doing anything wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

... Figured out as I was rereading my own question: `-1` is the function's middle line, which shifts the whole graph down by `-1`. The inequality I started with has no solutions because, indeed, the function never evaluates to a `y` greater than zero. I was greatly anxious, and as I just can't handle these kinds of situations, mistakes like this I guess may happen! Didn't delete the question, because hey, it might eventually help anybody who'd find him/herself in the same, apparently stupid, situation. :) Cheers!

Comment: Of course $\sin 2x \ge 1$ is true for $2x=k\pi$ or $x=k\frac\pi2$. You almost mentioned that. So you get negative sign and zero.